# How to print gantt-charts generated on web using python?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, trac, genshi

I want to print or save gantt-chart(in pdf format). These charts are generated on web after a particular input. Our chart is a plug-in for Trac. I have used Genshi library to generate charts.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source python library for generating PDF files by [Report Labs](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/). I've not used it myself, but other questions & answers on SO have revolved around this library, [Report Lab Toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information about your plugin?  There is a [gantt chart plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GanttChartPlugin) on [trac-hacks.org](http://trac-hacks.org); is that the one you are using, or a custom one?  If custom, is it available as Open Source somewhere so we can see what you are doing?

If you implemented this as a wiki macro, you can use the [WikiToPdf](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracWikiToPdfPlugin) plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org) to convert HTML to PDF. From their example website:

```
weasyprint http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html CSS21-intro.pdf -s http://weasyprint.org/samples/CSS21-print.css
```

creates a PDF file based on the HTML page and CSS provided. This is a python implementation.